# Flair without borders

Tags: feature-request, flair

Would it be possible to allow a second variable in the flair image URL to indicate that you'd like the image to be border-less?

Or, perhaps, remove the border altogether by default?

I've run into several situations where the border around the flair (which is part of the image) prevents the flair from blending into a design properly. Usually, this happens when you place it in an unordered list that provides borders between items in the list.

We can always specify our *own* border when using flair, but it is extremely difficult to make the border go away if we don't want it.

**Update**

It is possible to accomplish this using a [CSS trick](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88698/flair-without-borders/88705#88705) as Dori pointed out, however the purpose of this request is to eliminate the need to do that.

Comment: You could always try [StackImage 2](http://stackapps.com/questions/2400/stackimage-2-create-your-own-unique-custom-flair) now - it supports borderless flair.

Answer (score 2):

Any problem with using ?theme=clean ?

[image]

Instead of normal one?

[image]

Comment: Hum, why normal flair is 100 off, need to do bug report.

Comment: Lol, I didn't even notice that. :)

Comment: Because I end up with a white (although border-less) image in a div with a gray background color (it's not transparent) :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to mess with the tags themselves, just use a little CSS:

```
<div style="background-color:#EEE;height:58px;width:208px;padding:20px;
    position:relative;">
    <img src="http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair/50049.png"
        style="height:58px;width:208px;clip:rect(1px,206px,56px,1px);
        position:absolute;">
</div>
```

Gives you this:
[image]

The only parts that actually matter are the `style` attributes.

Comment: I've been working with (and even got some help with) CSS tricks to do it prior to posting this, but hadn't tried that yet. I'll give it a go.

Comment: @Tim - if you have any trouble with the above (it can be a little persnickity), let me know.

Comment: @Dori, Thanks - I'll try it shortly. My last attempt resulted in lopping off my head :/

Comment: @Dori - Thank you, that worked with a little fumbling and some br tags to help line up the stuff under it. Still, I'm hoping people can go 'border-less' without having to use css tricks :)

Comment: @Tim What kind of fun would it be without tricky CSS hacks? ;-) Glad I could help.

Comment: @Dori - If we could find a way to work a magic number in here, this would be _perfect_.