# Flair reputation is 100 off on default theme

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flair

After answering [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88698/flair-without-borders) one, I noticed that this user's flair default theme's reputation is **100** off.

[image]

Could be a bug?

Comment: I think this is probably the same as [How often is the flair image refreshed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65941/145982); it was cached because it's the one he actually uses

Comment: I'm having the same issue over a year later.

Comment: @Oded so you confirm the default flair is cached longer than the others? EDIT: never mind, it's confirmed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69401/why-is-my-flair-not-updated-with-my-actual-reputation-score?rq=1#comment317415_120182).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - It isn't. But it is likely to be generated at a different time than the others (if you have your flair link on your blog, for instance). All 4 would be generated at the same time only if you go to the flair page.

Comment: @Oded OK, good to know that. Don't you think it's better be explained in a post though? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce with my flair, maybe the classic version was last accessed and cached separate from the others 100 rep ago. Then when this image was taken, the classic used the cached version while the other three were generated with the new higher rep.

Comment: I cannot able to repro this for myself too. I originally thought because of cache, but when I check his profile, he only earned 35 reps today when I post this. and my reps for today also similar numbers but mine was updated, so I was thinking something other than cache issue. But let's see, caching could be special for him, who knows.

Comment: @YOU: I suppose it would depend on when the images were cached, he did earn 90 rep the previous day ... but like you said, lets see.

Comment: I'm having the same issue over a year later.

Answer (score 1):

Flair images are not guaranteed to be generated at the same time. For example, it is likely that someone will have a flair image using a specific theme on their blog.

This can cause the following:

- Assuming flair is not cached at the moment, someone visits the blog
- Flair for the specific theme is generated and cached
- User gets more reputation
- Someone visits their flair page - all other flair is generated, with different reputation